# OpenCV 2.8.4 installation under Linux for Java development

Tags: java, linux, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.4.8 on my Fedora Linux. Unfortunately for some reason java module won't install. I believe some dependencies are missing. Below you can see log from installation. JDK from Oracle (ver. 1.7.0_45-b18) is installed. "Java tests: NO" from log bothers me. Any idea?

```
[root@localhost release]# cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for assert.h
-- Looking for assert.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for jbg_newlen
-- Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for search.h
-- Looking for search.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found JPEG: libjpeg  
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   package 'gtk+-2.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   package 'gthread-2.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   package 'libv4l1' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Found PythonInterp: /bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.5", minimum required is "2.0") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "2.7.5")
-- Found apache ant 1.9.2: /bin/ant
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.8 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.13.8-200.fc20.x86_64 x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /bin/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    NO
--     GThread :                    NO
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 62)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/lukasz/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /bin/python2 (ver 2.7.5)
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /bin/ant (ver 1.9.2)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java/include /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java/include
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /bin/pdflatex
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/lukasz/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.8/release
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/lukasz/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.8/release
```

Answer (score 0):

Works now :) Simply had to set JAVA_HOME system variable before installation. In my case:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/
```